# emplace_back is not creating inplace object

Tags: c++, c++11

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    class test{
        public:
        test(){
        cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;
    }
     test(const test& obj){
      cout<<"copy constructor called"<<endl;
     }
     test(test&& obj){
      cout<<"Move constructor called"<<endl;
    }     
    };
  int main()
  {
      vector<test> vec;
      vec.emplace_back(test());

      return 0;
  }
```

When i run above program I expected emplace_back to create object in vector in place.Thus "constructor called" should have been output since emplace_back would avoid creating temporary object.

But the **output** is:

```
constructor called
Move constructor called
```

Here, temporary object is created just like push_back. Please explain.

Comment: You create the object yourself with `test()`. Remove that.

Answer (score 3):

[`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) doesn't construct temporaries, but you constructed a temporary object explicitly by `test()`, then the new element is added to the `vector` from the temporary by the move constructor.

You can just

```
vec.emplace_back();
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! ..Got it. But If I want to add a test object which was already created before emplace_back then will emplace_back work same as push_back?? If yes then when should I use emplace_back?? only when I know constructor arguments?

Comment: @bajirao Yes and yes. If you already have the object then `emplace_back` and `push_back` work in same way. If you know the arguments accepted by the constructor of the class, and you don't want to construct the temporary object, then you could use `emplace_back`, which would construct the element in-place.

Answer (score 1):

With `emplace_back(test())` you already created an object outside of `emplace_back` and it has a move constructor so it is move-constructed. So you should call it without any argument for this case. Then you will not see any copy/move constructor calls.

```cpp
vec.emplace_back(); // Will create a test object with constructor `test()` internally
```

To further understand, if your `test` class have more constructors, you can give `emplace_back` with those constructors. For example,

```cpp
class test {
  ...
  test(int a, int b);
  test(const char* c);
};
```

And you can do this.

```cpp
vec.emplace_back(1, 2);
vec.emplace_back("abcd");
```

This does not create redundant object which is cannot be done with `push_back`.

Comment: Thanks Hanjoung! ..Got it. But If I want to add a test object which was already created before emplace_back then will emplace_back work same as push_back?? If yes then when should I use emplace_back?? only when I know constructor arguments?

Comment: @bajirao Yes. In that case, both works same way. I think it is always good to use `emplace_back` as long as you are using C++11 or later. But still `push_back` is needed for legacy code compatibility.

Comment: IMHO `emplace_back` was introduced from C++11 since it requires variadic templates.

Answer (score 1):

With `emplace_back`, the method already knows what class type that you're adding to your vector (you name it when initialising the vector), so the input arguments for `emplace_back` is *only the arguments* for the constructor that you want to call (typically you want to avoid the copy constructor, whose argument is an object of the same class):

```
struct A
{
    A (int a, int b, int c)
    {
    // do something
    }

    A (const A & other)
    {
    //do something else
    }
};

std::vector<A> array;

array . emplace_back (1, 2, 3);
// the above finds the constructor with these input arguments
// makes the new object within the vector - no copy

A obj (4, 5, 6);

array . emplace_back ( obj );
// the above looks for the constructor with this object (A)
// it finds a constructor (the copy constructor) and copies

array . emplace_back ( A (1,2,3) );
// the above first processes the inner part: making a new A object
// then searches for a constructor with that argument (an object A)
// in this case that's the copy constructor
```

In your case you were wanting to call a constructor with no arguments. This is why you want to use `emplace_back()` with no arguments to use this vector method correctly.